# How can I overlay text over a bar in a bar chart using D3.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I've built a bar chart that currently renders like so

[image]

I would like to display the value of each bar on top of the rectangle. How can I do this?

Here's my component for reference. Thank you.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { select, axisBottom, axisLeft, scaleLinear, scaleBand } from "d3";
import styles from './BarChart.module.scss';

export type IBarChartProps = {
  data: {label: string, value: number}[];
  height: number;
  width: number;
}

const MAX_STAT = 200;

function BarChart({ data, height, width } : IBarChartProps) {
  const svgRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);

    const xScale = scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map((value, index) => index.toString()))
      .range([0, width])
      .padding(0.1);

    const yScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, MAX_STAT])
      .range([height, 0]);

    const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale)
      .ticks(data.length)
      .tickFormat((_, index) => data[index].label);

    svg
      .select("#x-axis")
      .style("transform", `translateY(${height}px)`)
      .style("font-size", '16px')
      .call(xAxis as any);

    const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);
    svg
      .select("#y-axis")
      .style("font-size", '16px')
      .call(yAxis as any);

    svg.selectAll('g.tick');

    svg
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .join("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("transform", "scale(1, -1)")
      .attr("x", (_, index) => xScale(index.toString()) as any)
      .attr("y", -height)
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
      .transition()
      .attr("fill","#0072BD")
      .attr("height", (value) => height - yScale(value.value));

    svg
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .append('text')
      .text('score')
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.BarChart__Container} style={{ height: `${height + 50}px`, width: `${width + 50}px` }}>
      <svg className={styles.BarChart} ref={svgRef} style={{ height: `${height}px`, width: `${width}px` }}>
        <g id="x-axis" />
        <g id="y-axis" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BarChart;
```

I've attempted something along the lines of the following within the `useEffect`, but I couldn't get text to appear. The inspector does indicate that the text tags were added to the svg, but nothing visible appears in the chart.

svg.selectAll(".bar").append("text").text('hello world')

Answer (score 0):

Create `bar` as a `g` element instead of `rect`.

Append `rect` and `text` to `g` as children:

```
const bars = svg
  .selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .join("g")
  .classed("bar", true);
      
bars.append("rect")
  .style("transform", "scale(1, -1)")
  .attr("x", (_, index) => xScale(index.toString()))
  .attr("y", -height)
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .transition()
  .attr("fill","#0072BD")
  .attr("height", (value) => height - yScale(value.value));
      
bars.append("text")
  .text(d => d.value)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("y", d => height - d.value - 4)
  .attr("x", (_, index) => xScale(index.toString()) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
```

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useRef, useMemo} = React;

const MAX_STAT = 200;

const BarChart = ({ data, height, width }) => {
  const svgRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);

    const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map((value, index) => index.toString()))
      .range([0, width])
      .padding(0.1);

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, MAX_STAT])
      .range([height, 0]);

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
      .ticks(data.length)
      .tickFormat((_, index) => data[index].label);

    svg
      .select("#x-axis")
      .style("transform", `translateY(${height}px)`)
      .style("font-size", '16px')
      .call(xAxis);

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    svg
      .select("#y-axis")
      .style("font-size", '16px')
      .call(yAxis)

    svg.selectAll('g.tick');

    const bars = svg
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .join("g")
      .classed("bar", true);
      
    bars.append("rect")
      .style("transform", "scale(1, -1)")
      .attr("x", (_, index) => xScale(index.toString()))
      .attr("y", -height)
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
      .transition()
      .attr("fill","#0072BD")
      .attr("height", (value) => height - yScale(value.value));
      
   bars.append("text")
        .text(d => d.value)
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('y', d => height - d.value - 4)
      .attr("x", (_, index) => xScale(index.toString()) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)

  }, [data]);

  return (
      <svg ref={svgRef} width={width} height={height}>
        <g id="x-axis" />
        <g id="y-axis" />
      </svg>
  );
};

const data = [{label: 'A', value: 10}, {label: 'B', value: 20}, {label: 'C', value: 30}];
ReactDOM.render(<BarChart data={data} width={300} height={150} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.2/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: Thank you
This is almost what I need but every time the graph data changes, a new rect and text is added to each g element which breaks the graph.

How can I overwrite the existing rect and text inside of each g instead of appending new ones whenever the data changes?

Comment: I would suggest replacing `join` with `enter` / `exit`/ `merge` pattern and updating rects and texts after merge